# Como passar parâmetros em função executada via ng-click quando esta estiver numa lista de botões?

Tags: ionic, parâmetros

Usando o framework IONIC tenho a seguinte situação, em um index.html existe uma lista de itens tipo input onde serão informados pelo usuário o seu respectivo username, e-mail e senha e em um determinado botão tipo submit é chamado a função savePerson(cadastro) passando o parametro cadastro que deveria conter as informações digitadas pelo usuário para salvar o registro, no entanto no App.js responsável pelo controle desta operação, o parametro cadastro chega inválido na função savePerson.

Alguém poderia informar como faço para resolver este problema diante deste cenário?

Abaixo segue os trechos dos códigos

---

### INDEX.HTML

```
<ion-pane class="login-custom">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Minha Pelada <span>picapau amarelo(domingo)</span></h1>
    <ion-list class= "list-inset">
      <ion-item class= "item-input">
        <i class= "icon ion-ios-person-outline placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type= "text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.username" id="username" placeholder= "username">
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class = "item-input">
        <i class = "icon ion-ios-email-outline placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type = "text" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.email" id="email" placeholder= "email">
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class = "item-input">
        <i class = "icon ion-ios-locked-outline placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type = "password" name="senha" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.senha" id="senha" placeholder= "senha">
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class= "item-button button-first">
        <button type="submit" class= "button button-block button-calm" ng-click="savePerson(cadastro)"> Criar conta</button>
       </ion-item>
        <button class= "button button-block icon-left ion-social-facebook button-positive"> Entrar com Facebook </button> 
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class= "item-button">
        <button class= "button button-block button-clear"> Já tem uma Conta? Clique aqui para Entrar em MinhaPelada </button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

---

### APP.JS

```
  $scope.savePerson = function(params) {
    alert('Usuário Informado: ' + params.username + ' Senha Informada: ' + params.senha );
    var PeopleObject = Parse.Object.extend("PeopleObject");
    var person = new PeopleObject();
    person.set("username", username);
    person.set("senha", senha);
    person.save(null, {});
};
```

---

### ERRO REPORTADO PELO CONSOLE DO BROWSER GOOGLE CHROME

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.savePerson (app.js:34)
    at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27643), <anonymous>:4:300)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65429
    at ChildScope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at ChildScope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30500)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65428)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16792)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16780)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2942)
(anonymous) @ ionic.bundle.js:26799
(anonymous) @ ionic.bundle.js:23512
$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:30505
(anonymous) @ ionic.bundle.js:65428
defaultHandlerWrapper @ ionic.bundle.js:16792
eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:16780
triggerMouseEvent @ ionic.bundle.js:2953
tapClick @ ionic.bundle.js:2942
tapTouchEnd @ ionic.bundle.js:3069
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O atribudo `params` da função `savePerson` está como `undefined`, `params` é uma referência para o objeto `cadastro` que você passa em `ng-click="savePerson(cadastro)"` então o `cadastro` está `undefined`.

**O erro**

O erro é porque você está tentando acessar atributos de um objeto que não foi criado.

**Solução:**

No controller em `app.js` inicie o objeto `cadastro`:

```
$scope.cadastro = {};
```

Comment: Glauber, obrigado por sua atenção!

Comment: Glauber, muito obrigado por sua atenção! Eu tentei iniciar o objeto da seguinte forma:

      $scope.savePerson = function(params) {
        $scope.cadastro = {};
        alert('Usuário Informado: ' + cadastro.username + ' Senha Informada: ' + cadastro.senha );
        var PeopleObject = Parse.Object.extend("PeopleObject");
...
    };

Mas, infelizmente aconteceu outro tipo de erro, segue abaixo:

ReferenceError: cadastro is not defined
    at ChildScope.$scope.savePerson (app.js:35)
...

Você pode informar o que eu fiz de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Glauber, descobri o porquê do novo erro, era a região onde foi iniciado o objeto cadastro, eu havia colocado no local errado, fiz a mudança deste local e agora o sistema já reconhece os parâmetros passados no objeto cadastro. Muito obrigado pela sua dica! Segue abaixo o trecho do código corrigido:

```
example.controller("ExampleController", function($scope) {

      $scope.cadastro = {};

      $scope.savePerson = function(cadastro) {

        alert('Usuário Informado: ' + cadastro.username + ' Senha Informada: ' + cadastro.senha );

        var PeopleObject = Parse.Object.extend("PeopleObject");
        var person = new PeopleObject();

        person.set("username", cadastro.username);
        person.set("senha", cadastro.senha);
        person.save(null, {});

      };
```

Comment: De nada @ita, se minha resposta foi uma solução, marque-a como resolvida. Att